# How do you pass in a dynamic percentage into a CSS variable from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-variables

The general idea of what I'm doing is that I have a React component that I've created, where I'm rendering it out based on dynamic data that gets mapped through. The wrapper div has a height of 100%, and the child div inside of it would (ideally) take up a vertical section of the div based on a percentage that gets calculated each time the component is rendered.

For example, a component gets rendered and the percentage associated with that component is 70%. I would like to pass in that 70% value into the CSS, and have it take up 70% of the parent div.

This isn't my exact code, but it should help give you a general idea of the layout.

**ReactJS**

```
function Bucket({ numForChildDivHeight, numForParentDivHeight }) {

// to calculate the percentage of the child div, and set the --dynamic-height to that percentage
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dynamic-height',
    numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight);

    return (
        <div className='parent-div'>
            <div className='child-div'>
                // misc. information
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
    --dynamic-height: 0%;
}

.parent-div {
    height: 100%;
}

.child-div {
    height: var(--dynamic-height);
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the equation (numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight) returns a double instead of a percentage and therefore CSS treats it as such. Is there a way for me to convert the double into a percentage and pass that in to the CSS variable? I appreciate any help you've got.

**Edit for anyone looking at this in the future:**
I was able to solve this by calculating the percentage for each child div, storing that in an object, and then passing the percentage into the component with an inline style tag. An example implementation can be found below:

```
function Bucket({ numForChildDivHeight, numForParentDivHeight }) {


const heightPercentage = numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight * 100 + '%';

const bucketStyle = {
    height: heightPercentage,
}

    return (
        <div className='parent-div'>
            <div className='child-div' style={heightPercentage}>
                // misc. information
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This implementation circumvents the need for a CSS variable, so that can be removed from the CSS. Thank you to the users who commented and helped out!

Comment: Your CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) `--dynamic-height` is set to use a string ending with `%`. Have you tried concatenating your calculation with `%` character at the end? e.g. `(numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight) + %` or `\`${numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight}%\``

Comment: @BumhanYu thanks for your help! For some reason I thought that if I concatenated the '%' onto the percentage, it would recognize the percentage as a string and not a numerical value. Dumb mistake on my part, but thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Think you can do this (if you are using class),

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("child-div");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].style.height = (numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight) + '%';
}
```

or with id it's easier,

```
document.getElementById("child-div").style.height = (numForChildDivHeight / numForParentDivHeight) + '%';
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I tried using className in a prior attempt at solving my problem but it would set all of the components to the height percentage of the final component that gets rendered. Your solution helped me solve it though, so thank you for your help!